# How to hide these 2 element in css / less?

Tags: magento2, bundled-product, less-css

[image]In Magento2 I want to hide the price-notice and the qty-holder from the bundle product page. I want to edit the _custom.less page but not sure what to write in it. Any help would help. Thanks!

[image: qty holder]

[image: price notice]

[image: screenshot]

[image]

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the page you are editing with the items you want removed circled? The images you added aren't as helpful as that would be. Also what version of Magento 2? thanks

Comment: @morgan  I figured out for the Qty box, but can't seem to find the right css to remove the price-notice  +$x.xx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to search for those classes in the repository/source code, and then use the same nesting in your _custom.less file. The path to get to that class needs to match what it is currently. You can also see this in the browser by inspecting those elements. The classes themselves will need either `visibility: hidden;` or `display: none;` depending on what your trying to achieve exactly. You can also test this in the browser inspector before putting in your file. When done, deploy your static content `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` and if cache is enabled, clear it `php bin/magento cache:flush`.

Comment: What i'm having issue if figuring out those class. I managed to do exactly that for the QTY box, need to figure out the price-notice +$X.xx now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Right click on it and select inspect element. You should see the class listed in the styles. It should also highlight the element on the page when you mouse over the element in the inspector. It's possible that text is part of the greater string that is the bundle option name

Comment: [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/llmPX.png  I've been trying different combinaison but can't find the right one. For the QTY I used :                          
    .bundle-options-container .nested .field.qty:last-child
{
    display : none;
}

Comment: Add a screenshot of that class style from the inspector.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/llmPX.png

Comment: Nope, not that. I'm looking for this https://monosnap.com/file/fkCAHLLtIk0wCVYPkmBnuN1Y8m54Td

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/llmPX.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93413/discussion-between-mlunt-and-emili).